# Port 6667 can't be reached outside of localhost

Tags: linux, iptables, irc

I've got IRCD-Hybrid installed with the following listen config:

```
/* listen {}: contain information about the ports ircd listens on (OLD P:) */
listen {
        /* port: the specific port to listen on.  if no host is specified
         * before, it will listen on all available IPs.
         *
         * ports are seperated via a comma, a range may be specified using ".."
         */

        /* port: listen on all available IPs, ports 6665 to 6669 */
        # host = "127.0.0.1";   # change this!
        #port = 6665 .. 6669;
        port = 6667;
};
```

and the following `iptables -L` output:

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ircd
```

I can connect to the IRC server through irssi on the server, but when I try and connect from outside the server, I get "no route to host".

nmap confirms that the port is not open. What else can I try?

Comment: Run `iptables -nL`. Is it allowing port 194 instead of 6667? What is your output of `netstat -tan`?

Comment: Shows 6667. `netstat -tan` here: http://pastebin.com/Kebdmb3V

Comment: Can you add the full `iptables -nL` output too?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/65wv8x68

Comment: If the policy is always ACCEPT, you don't need rules. Is the client trying an IPv6 connection? Can you watch network traffic with tcpdump or wireshark?

Comment: Did some more research; realized my VPS provider doesn't open all ports by default. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some more research: my VPS provider doesn't open all ports by default.